# Add telemetrics to gps file format

Tags: gps, gpx

I've created my own data file using gps information and loads of sensor data.
I'd like to create a gps file which will add this information to the geographic location. Unfortunately most common gps file types don't support additional data like the [gpx file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPS_Exchange_Format) for example.

Sensor data would be telemetric data like humidity, temperature, etc.

So my question is: 
What is best practice in order to create a unified gps file with the possibility to add additional data.

I've created my own data file using gps information and loads of sensor data. I'd like to create a gps file which will add this information to the geographic location. Unfortunately most common gps file types don't support additional data like the gpx file format for example.

Sensor data would be telemetric data like humidity, temperature, etc.

So my question is: What is best practice in order to create a unified gps file with the possibility to add additional data.

**Additional Info:**
Video length: 6:18:05 hrs (378:04,500 Seconds)

Data record first timestamp: 10:03:25 o'clock
Data record last timestamp: 15:16:03 o'clock
==> Data record length: 5:12:38 hrs (312:31.000 Seconds)

Here are the pont in times for three different sync points.

```
     1. Take-Off   =>   2.Explosion (balloon) =>    3.Landing  
video   23:53:352         184:19.886                  241:20:765  
data    15:50.105         149:15.014                  196:36.998  
offset  -08:03.183        -35:04.872                  -44:43:767
```

As you can see, the offset is getting bigger the longer the video/data runs.

Comment: You are incorrect about the gpx format - you can stick as many extra data elements/tags as you want in a gpx, the problem is getting other software to recognize them. You talk about a "gps file". What does that mean exactly? Something that can be loaded into a GPS unit? By what manufacturer? Or are you simply wanting a geospatial component to your data, in which case you're looking at a GIS/spatial database and there are a number of options.

Comment: Regarding to this article (http://www.topografix.com/gpx_manual.asp) there are required and optional attributes in the GPX definition. Thise attributes don't match the information that I'd like to store.
Actually I've created a sql database and extracted the data into a gpx file in order to use it with dashware (video telemetric software), so this is actually the part of software that recognizes the software using a self made/modified gpx profile. The file would get loaded into dashware.
Back to my question.. how would I store this information in an gpx file as additional attributes?

Comment: You might take a look at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/166952/ which contains an answer linking to http://www.gdal.org/drv_gpx.html (specifically, the subject of extensions). That said, based on the [DashWare FAQ](http://www.dashware.net/faq/), you  might be better off using the csv format rather than gpx. BTW, thanks for bringing DashWare to my attention. I've been looking for something like that for a while and there are other questions here on the subject of how to do what it does.

Comment: That FAQ helped me a lot. I got the map working using CSV format but the asynchronous times are still a problem. I've added some information to my originally post that I think helps to understand the problem.
Off-Topic: Alternives are: Garmin Virb or RaceRender LLC